# set-up and tear-down method for multiple test modules

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, python-unittest

I have a number of tests, scattered among different test modules and classes. I need to start up/tear down a docker container before/after running the tests, but neither `setUpClass()` nor `setUpModule()` seems appropriate. How do I specify set-up and tear-down methods for multiple modules?

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class for all your tests with in which you place your common `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` methods:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpClass(self):
        ...set up docker stuff...

    def tearDownClass(self):
        ...tear down docker stuff...
```

Now have all of your test classes inherit from that base class:

```
from mymodule.mytestcase import MyTestCase

class TestMyNiftyFeature(MyTestCase):
    def test_feature(self):
        ...test things here...
```

This will run the setup/teardown methods before and after each class, which is generally what you want because you want your tests to be self-contained so that you can run tests in one file without running tests in another.

Comment: In my specific case, I'd rather start the docker container only once though since it is quite time consuming. Repeating the procedure for ~10 test classes would be unacceptably slow in my case.

Comment: Can you reverse things and instead of having your tests start the container instead run your tests *inside* a container?  E.g., something like `docker run --rm -u $UID -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD myimage pytest`.

Comment: Basically I am testing an RPC server and I intensionally do not want to run the tests in the same container to resemble a real world scenario as closely as possible. The idea is to have a client container (where I run the tests in) and a server container that I can only contact via HTTPS.